# How do you find the sign extension of a hex number in ARM?

Tags: arm

To find the branch address, for example:

`0x28: BNE Prod  1AFFFFFA`

The current PC would be `0x28 + 0x08 = 0x30`

The offset would be `FFFFFA<<2`, and then sign extended.

`FFFFFA<<2 = 3FFFFE8`

How would the sign extension for `3FFFFE8` be?

`03FFFFE8`?

`F3FFFFE8`?

I'm confused as the answers I've seen online give the sign extension as `0xFFFFFFE8`, while for let's say `03FFF4`, the sign extension is given to be `0x0003FFF4`

---

Speculation: Would the sign extend work like this -

From `3FFFFE8`, take the MSB 3, convert to decimal - 0011. Ignore the 0s to the left, so 1 is the MSB and we extend 1s after it, thus making it F instead of 3? Giving us the answer, `FFFFFFF4`

Meanwhile for `03FFF4`, the MSB would be the 0, which in binary is 0000 leading to an extension of 0s?

Comment: Sign extension is only needed while shifting right, hence it's called ASR (arithmetic shift right) while non sign extending shifting right is called LSR (logical shift right)

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE I don't think that's the case, since it's mentioned we need to sign extend the result - and the result in usually 24-28 bits, while we need 32 bits. The remaining 4-8 bits need to be sign extensions

Comment: Why bother asking then? Just believe what you want. BTW 3 isn't the MSB but 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look at the encoding of the instruction. If the immediate field is considered a signed offset, then the msbit OF THAT FIELD is the bit you sign extend.  If it is a 7 bit field bits 6:0 then bit 6 is the one you extend as far left as you need to do the math required to compute the final address.   If it is an 11 bit field then bit 10 and so on.

In instructions like these the immediate is often not a byte offset but a halfword or word offset.  So you can choose to sign extend it after you shift left or before, that is your choice.  I find it easier to sign extend first and have a complete immediate then do any other math like turning it into a byte offset, or adding fixed offsets, etc.

any thing assembly language or disassembly related is not relevant really it is the choice of the author of that tool as to how they want to represent data.  some might just put a -10 in there to indicate 10 instructions back.

```
here: 
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    bne here

    Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <here>:
   0:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  10:   1afffffa    bne 0 <here>

0x1AFFFFFA
000110101111......11111010

0001 condition code NE (Z=0)
1010 b (branch) instruction
1111......11111010 signed_immed_24
```

the msbit of the immediate is a 1 so sign extend that to 32 bits

```
0xFFFFFFFA
```

from a version of the ARM documentation

```
<target_address>
Specifies the address to branch to. The branch target address is calculated by:
1. Sign-extending the 24-bit signed (two’s complement) immediate to 32 bits.
2. Shifting the result left two bits.
3. Adding this to the contents of the PC, which contains the address of the branch instruction plus 8.
The instruction can therefore specify a branch of approximately ±32MB.
```

Before adjustments this offset points at how many (32 bit, this is the ARM version) words to branch.

```
0xFFFFFFFA = -6
```

-6 in this case

```
here: nop      -6
    nop        -5
    nop        -4
    nop        -3
x:  bne here   -2
x+1            -1
x+2            0
```

So the assembler did it's job and put the right offset in there.

```
0x00FFFFFA sign extended to 0xFFFFFFFA
0xFFFFFFFA<<2 = 0xFFFFFFE8 (clipped at 32 bits)
0xFFFFFFE8 = -24

here: nop      -24
    nop        -20
    nop        -16
    nop        -12
x:  bne here   -8
x+1            -4
x+2            0     

0xFFFFFFE8 + 8 = 0xFFFFFFF0 = -16

here: nop      -16
    nop        -12
    nop        -8
    nop        -4
    bne here   -0
```

Let's put some addresses in here and work it forward.

```
        here: 
0x1008:     nop
0x100C:     nop
0x1010:     nop
0x1014:     nop
0x1018:     bne here

destination - branch instruction
0x1008 - (0x1018+8) = 0x1008 - 0x1020
0x1008 - 0x1020 = 0xFFFFFFE8
0xFFFFFFE8/4 = 0xFFFFFFFA
0xFFFFFFFA & 0x00FFFFFF = 0x00FFFFFA signed_offset_24 field
0x0A000000 | 0x00FFFFFA = 0x0AFFFFFA opcode field
0x10000000 | 0x0AFFFFFA = 0x1AFFFFFA condition field
0x1AFFFFFA bne -6
```

The math works in either direction branching forward or backward or a branch to self.

Comment: Can you explain this with an example say for 1AFFFFFA and how you'd get FFFFFFE8?